# Pass multidimensional array from javascript to servicestack

Tags: multidimensional-array, servicestack

I want to pass 2 dimensional array from javascript code to servicestack service. Please let me know what is the best possible way to handle that data on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays, you should use nested Lists instead, e.g `List<List<int>>`.